# ng-repeat with a big JSON

Tags: json, angularjs

I have an AngularJS variable `var vm = this;` which contains a big JSON format data:

```
vm.data = {
    "sites": [{
        "siteName": "A",
            "countries": [{
                "country": "DE",
                "servers": [{
                    "serverType": "master",
                    "URL": ""
                },{
                    "serverType": "slave",
                    "URL": ""
                }]
            }]

        },{
            "siteName": "B",
            "countries": [{
                "country": "IT",
                "servers": [{
                    "serverType": "master",
                    "URL": ""
                },{
                    "serverType": "slave",
                    "URL": ""
                }]
            },{
                "country": "NL",
                "servers": [{
                    "serverType": "master",
                    "URL": ""
                },{
                    "serverType": "slave",
                    "URL": ""
                }]
            }]
        }]
};
```

I want to put this data in a table

I use "c" because of the the "controller (which is the name of my controller) as c".

```
<tr ng-repeat="site in c.data.sites">
            <td>{{ site.siteName }}</td>
            <td>{{ site.countries }}</td>
            <td>{{ site.countries.name }}</td>
</tr>
```

The first *td* works perfectly, the second displays everything that is contained in the countries set, and the last doesn’t display anything.

I tried to declare `vm.data.sites.countries`, but it failed.

Can you shed some light on this?

Comment: What are you trying to display? I can't tell from your HTML.

Comment: I try to display, at this time, the name of the country of each site.

Comment: countries is array, you need to loop or access it with index, or filter with | json. also there is no .name in country object.

Comment: countries is an array access like countries[index].property

Comment: Oh ok, is it a common way to access to this type of JSON data ?

Comment: use a nested `ng-repeat` to show the countries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `countries` is an array, so if you want to list every country you can access every name of the country objects (your name attribute for a country object is `country`) with a new loop (`ng-repeat`).

```
<tr ng-repeat="site in c.data.sites">
            <td>{{ site.siteName }}</td>
            <td>{{ site.countries }}</td>
            <td>
                <span ng-repeat="country in site.countries>
                     {{country.country}}
                     <span ng-if="!$last">, </span>
                </span>
            </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you're not really referencing your keys appropriately.

```
<tr ng-repeat="site in c.data.sites">
   <td>{{ site.siteName }}</td>
   <td>
      <span ng-repeat="country in site.countries">
          {{ country.country }}
          <span ng-hide="$last">, </span>
      </span>
   </td>
</tr>
```